# Mongo Java queries, DBRef, and one-to-many relationships

Tags: java, mongodb, one-to-many, mongodb-query

I have implemented a relationship between two DBObjects using a DBRef, as described @ http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-types/

For the sake of this question, we'll use the following two Java objects:

```
Foo { String name, ... }
Bar { Foo foo, ... }
```

The relationship works; I can see the DBRef BSON-object as an embedded document within any given instance of Bar while I'm at the MongoDB command-line, and when I query instances of Bar from Java, instances of Foo  (and **not** DBRef) are presented as embedded documents.

My question is this: how can I search for instances of Bar which have 'foo' fields with a specific value for the 'name' field?

Comment: You cannot. MongoDB does not perforrm "JOINS" in any way and the general intention is to rather "embed" related data within the document in the same collection. A `DBRef` is one concept supported in some drivers where it may "magically" load that data from another collection when encountered. But this is not a "JOIN" and the data from another collection cannot be queried. Creating manual references is generally preferred logic as described in the [manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/).

Comment: You're right, I discovered that painfully too late. The manual reference is tedious, but worth it if you don't want a _lot_ of repetitive data. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Your MongoDB search would look something like this, when querying the `Bar` collection:

`{ "foo.name": "some name to search for" }`

Comment: The question is asking about referencing the properties of of another document via a `DBRef` when making a query. You cannot do that.